# what'll happen to the muslim ummah who're following bida' unknowingly?

Tags: halal-haram, punishment, bidah

It is now very common for a group of people known as scholars to teach Islam and other ordinary Muslims do not have to learn Islam because there are scholars to inform people! And that is why different ideologies have emerged. The general public, especially the uneducated Muslims, are in trouble unknowingly. Everyone is claiming that they are following the Quran and Sahih Hadith!

***Now my question is***, will it be a sin for those who follow the instructions of the so-called ulama to think that this act of worship (**which is actually an innovation,but they don't know and they're just following the particular ulama/sheikh with hard-core belief that this is only the correct way to please Allah**) is correct? Will Allah include them among those who practice innovation and punish them?

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaikum,

Allah S.W.T is the most just and fair. He will never punish us for something we did unintenationally or unknowingly. If we knew that it was wrong and still continued doing it, then we would be accountable for our deeds.

And Allah Knows Best.

May Allah Grant You Jannah.

Asalamualaikum...